# JavaFX Icon shows itself when I run the program from IDE, but refuses to show up, when I run the program from the target build

Tags: java, javafx, build, icons

I'm editing a Java GUI program, that manages a group of games and a DIY controller to work in accord. I added a new icon to "GamesScreen.fxml", added images to appropriate folder and added a few lines to the controller file "GameScreenController.java" as well as write a few lines to "GameScreen.css"

When I run the program using the button inside the IDE (NetBeans 17) it works flawlessly. However when I Build the program and run it from the .jar file the new icon does not show up. (But when I click the place where it should be, the appropriate functionality starts)
Images that other icons use are in the same folder as the new ones. So shouldn't be any issue with wrong paths.

I've tried to delete the target image folder to see if the rest of the icons will vanish too, but everything stayed the same.

What might be the problem ? I really don't have any idea.

GameScreenController.java

```
@FXML
    private void NewGameHandling(ActionEvent event) {
        currentInterpreter = new NewGameKeyboardInterpreter();
        showInterpreterDialogBox();
    }
```

GameScreen.css

```
#NewGameButton {
    -fx-background-image: url("/images/gameIcons/New_Game.png");
    -fx-background-position: center center;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-background-size: cover;
    -fx-border-width: 0;
}

#NewGameButton:hover {
    -fx-background-image: url("/images/gameIcons/New_Game_Focused.png");
 }
```

GamesScreen.fxml

```
<HBox id="gamesHBox" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="90.0" layoutY="422.0" prefHeight="288.0" prefWidth="1068.0" spacing="70.0">
         <children>
            <Button id="NewGameButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#NewGameHandling" prefHeight="152.0" prefWidth="149.0" stylesheets="@../styles/gameScreen.css" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
```

I shown only the relevant code snippets for reference. Let me know if you need full files.

Comment: Run `jar tvf` on the jar file.  See what is in it.

Comment: f it is as expected, review the [eden JavaFX resource guide](https://edencoding.com/where-to-put-resource-files-in-javafx/), which provides working examples of lookups for css image resources.  It may not make a difference, but is the app modular?  If so, you could try adjusting the path to something in the module or removing modularity (delete module-info.java).

Comment: @jewelsea My jar tvf returns over 9000 lines. None of which seems to be an error. Just listing of all possible files in the project I guess. All the files I edited are present including the png files I added. 

I've read the different ways to include resources from the link you provided, but didn't find an error. 
The search-bar in the project root folder didn't show any files that include a phrase "module" in it.

Comment: I have no other suggestions.

Comment: Search the results of the `jar tfv ` command to see if the image file is there, and if it is in the expected location. On UNIX-like systems you can do something like `jar tfv jarfile | grep imagefile`, replacing `jarfile` and `imagefile` with the actual file names.

Comment: @James_D 
The images are in expected locations. I've seen then in the listings fortunately.